# Identify overlapping date ranges by ID R

Tags: r, date

I have multiple rows with the same ID, and date ranges for each row. Sometimes, these date ranges overlap. I need to identify rows where they overlap.

EG Dataset:

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
id = c(1,1,1,  2,2,  3,3,3,3,3,3,  4,4,  5,5,5,5),
start_dt = c("01/01/2016", "12/02/2016", "03/12/2017",  "02/01/2016", 
"08/12/2016",  "01/01/2016", "03/05/2016", "05/07/2016", "07/01/2016", 
"09/04/2016", "10/10/2016",  "01/01/2016", "05/28/2016",  "01/01/2016", 
"06/05/2016", "08/25/2016", "11/01/2016"),  
end_dt =   c("12/01/2016", "03/14/2017", "05/15/2017",  "05/15/2016", 
"12/29/2016",  "03/02/2016", "04/29/2016", "06/29/2016", "08/31/2016", 
"09/25/2016", "11/29/2016",  "05/31/2016", "08/19/2016",  "06/10/2016", 
"07/25/2016", "08/29/2016", "12/30/2016"))
eg_data$row_n <- 1:nrow(eg_data)
```

Run the eg data above, and you see that the

start date for row 3 overlaps the end date of row 2 for ID #1; start date for row 13 overlaps the end date of row 12 for ID #4; and start date for row 15 overlaps the end date of row 14 for ID #5.

I need to be able to identify when this type of overlaps happens, for a single ID number.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert the dates to `Date` class. Then a self join on `id` and the intersection criteria will join all relevant overlapping rows. `overlap` is 1 if that row has an overlap and 0 otherwise.  `overlaps` lists the row numbers of the overlaps for that row.  We used row numbers `rowid` but we could replace each occurrence of it in the code below with `row_n` if desired.

```
library(sqldf)

fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
eg2 <- transform(eg_data, 
  start_dt = as.Date(start_dt, fmt),
  end_dt = as.Date(end_dt, fmt))


sqldf("select 
    a.*, 
    count(b.rowid) > 0 as overlap, 
    coalesce(group_concat(b.rowid), '') as overlaps
  from eg2 a
  left join eg2 b on a.id = b.id and 
                     not a.rowid = b.rowid and
                     ((a.start_dt between b.start_dt and b.end_dt) or
                     (b.start_dt between a.start_dt and a.end_dt))
  group by a.rowid
  order by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   id   start_dt     end_dt row_n overlap overlaps
1   1 2016-01-01 2016-12-01     1       0         
2   1 2016-12-02 2017-03-14     2       1        3
3   1 2017-03-12 2017-05-15     3       1        2
4   2 2016-02-01 2016-05-15     4       0         
5   2 2016-08-12 2016-12-29     5       0         
6   3 2016-01-01 2016-03-02     6       0         
7   3 2016-03-05 2016-04-29     7       0         
8   3 2016-05-07 2016-06-29     8       0         
9   3 2016-07-01 2016-08-31     9       0         
10  3 2016-09-04 2016-09-25    10       0         
11  3 2016-10-10 2016-11-29    11       0         
12  4 2016-01-01 2016-05-31    12       1       13
13  4 2016-05-28 2016-08-19    13       1       12
14  5 2016-01-01 2016-06-10    14       1       15
15  5 2016-06-05 2016-07-25    15       1       14
16  5 2016-08-25 2016-08-29    16       0         
17  5 2016-11-01 2016-12-30    17       0
```

Comment: This is what I need, and is even more helpful (ironically) given that I use SQL quite a bit, and this answer provides methods for R and SQL. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to get the same results using tidyverse?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be done pretty nicely with the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/index.html) package, a package for working with generic *interval vectors*, which is exactly what you have here. Interval vectors combine two columns of start/end points into a single interval column, which you can then manipulate with one of the many `iv_*()` functions. In particular, I used `iv_identify_group()` here to identify the within-id overlaps.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ivs)

eg_data <- tibble(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5),
  start_dt = c(
    "01/01/2016", "12/02/2016", "03/12/2017",  "02/01/2016", 
    "08/12/2016",  "01/01/2016", "03/05/2016", "05/07/2016", "07/01/2016", 
    "09/04/2016", "10/10/2016",  "01/01/2016", "05/28/2016",  "01/01/2016", 
    "06/05/2016", "08/25/2016", "11/01/2016"
  ),  
  end_dt = c(
    "12/01/2016", "03/14/2017", "05/15/2017", "05/15/2016", 
    "12/29/2016", "03/02/2016", "04/29/2016", "06/29/2016", "08/31/2016", 
    "09/25/2016", "11/29/2016",  "05/31/2016", "08/19/2016",  "06/10/2016", 
    "07/25/2016", "08/29/2016", "12/30/2016"
  )
)
eg_data$row_n <- 1:nrow(eg_data)

# Parse the dates into real Date objects and then combine the endpoints into an
# interval vector
eg_data <- eg_data %>%
  mutate(
    start_dt = as.Date(start_dt, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    end_dt = as.Date(end_dt, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    range = iv(start_dt, end_dt),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

# Note that they are half-open!
head(eg_data, n = 4)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      id row_n                    range
#>   <dbl> <int>               <iv<date>>
#> 1     1     1 [2016-01-01, 2016-12-01)
#> 2     1     2 [2016-12-02, 2017-03-14)
#> 3     1     3 [2017-03-12, 2017-05-15)
#> 4     2     4 [2016-02-01, 2016-05-15)

# For each id, identify the wider "overlap group" that each date range falls in
groups <- eg_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(group = iv_identify_group(range)) %>%
  group_by(group, .add = TRUE)

# Note that rows 2 and 3 are in the same overlap group within id 1
groups
#> # A tibble: 17 × 4
#> # Groups:   id, group [14]
#>       id row_n                    range                    group
#>    <dbl> <int>               <iv<date>>               <iv<date>>
#>  1     1     1 [2016-01-01, 2016-12-01) [2016-01-01, 2016-12-01)
#>  2     1     2 [2016-12-02, 2017-03-14) [2016-12-02, 2017-05-15)
#>  3     1     3 [2017-03-12, 2017-05-15) [2016-12-02, 2017-05-15)
#>  4     2     4 [2016-02-01, 2016-05-15) [2016-02-01, 2016-05-15)
#>  5     2     5 [2016-08-12, 2016-12-29) [2016-08-12, 2016-12-29)
#>  6     3     6 [2016-01-01, 2016-03-02) [2016-01-01, 2016-03-02)
#>  7     3     7 [2016-03-05, 2016-04-29) [2016-03-05, 2016-04-29)
#>  8     3     8 [2016-05-07, 2016-06-29) [2016-05-07, 2016-06-29)
#>  9     3     9 [2016-07-01, 2016-08-31) [2016-07-01, 2016-08-31)
#> 10     3    10 [2016-09-04, 2016-09-25) [2016-09-04, 2016-09-25)
#> 11     3    11 [2016-10-10, 2016-11-29) [2016-10-10, 2016-11-29)
#> 12     4    12 [2016-01-01, 2016-05-31) [2016-01-01, 2016-08-19)
#> 13     4    13 [2016-05-28, 2016-08-19) [2016-01-01, 2016-08-19)
#> 14     5    14 [2016-01-01, 2016-06-10) [2016-01-01, 2016-07-25)
#> 15     5    15 [2016-06-05, 2016-07-25) [2016-01-01, 2016-07-25)
#> 16     5    16 [2016-08-25, 2016-08-29) [2016-08-25, 2016-08-29)
#> 17     5    17 [2016-11-01, 2016-12-30) [2016-11-01, 2016-12-30)

# From there you can group by `id` and `group` and count them up
groups %>%
  count()
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#> # Groups:   id, group [14]
#>       id                    group     n
#>    <dbl>               <iv<date>> <int>
#>  1     1 [2016-01-01, 2016-12-01)     1
#>  2     1 [2016-12-02, 2017-05-15)     2
#>  3     2 [2016-02-01, 2016-05-15)     1
#>  4     2 [2016-08-12, 2016-12-29)     1
#>  5     3 [2016-01-01, 2016-03-02)     1
#>  6     3 [2016-03-05, 2016-04-29)     1
#>  7     3 [2016-05-07, 2016-06-29)     1
#>  8     3 [2016-07-01, 2016-08-31)     1
#>  9     3 [2016-09-04, 2016-09-25)     1
#> 10     3 [2016-10-10, 2016-11-29)     1
#> 11     4 [2016-01-01, 2016-08-19)     2
#> 12     5 [2016-01-01, 2016-07-25)     2
#> 13     5 [2016-08-25, 2016-08-29)     1
#> 14     5 [2016-11-01, 2016-12-30)     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>